# A-frame js camera rotation with look-controls

Tags: aframe

I am trying to rotate camera with look-controls.Camera is rotating fine without look-controls.Can somebody tell me how can i rotate camera with look-controls?

Comment: Please include code with your questions – I'm assuming if you have a demo "rotating fine without look-controls" there is some example code you could include here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to remove or disable `look-controls` if you're overriding camera rotation manually.

You can remove the component temporarily with `el.removeAttribute('look-controls')` and add the component again afterward.

Or use `el.setAttribute('look-controls', {enabled: false})` to disable the component.

Comment: sorry to intrude, but this did not work for me. I'm using the default glitch for aframe https://glitch.com/~aframe and I'm just launching the following commands in the console
`var camera = document.querySelector('[look-controls]');
camera.setAttribute('look-controls', {enabled: false});
camera.object3D.quaternion.copy(new THREE.Quaternion( 0.383, 0,0, 0.924));
camera.setAttribute('look-controls', {enabled: true})`
Removing the attribute does not work either.
If I start aframe with a declared camera, without look-controls, rotations are applied successfully.