# How to look to objects using lookAt() with a-frame camera component and look-controls

Tags: three.js, aframe

Goal: I want to create a Web based experience where the user need to see a series of elements on the scene and later, I want to leave the user explore alone.

I have several objects around the scene and I want the camera to look at them one by one.  I am using the lookat() method but is not working correctly.  I found this example on Threejs:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/135/
```

But my example is not working like the previous example.

---

After the answer of @Mugen87 is working but with a little modification:

```
document.getElementById('cam').sceneEl.camera.lookAt
```

Access the camera in this way. You can see the example here:

```
https://glitch.com/~aframe-lookat-cam-not-working
```

Please click on the button "animate camera".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could make it worked. I am new in Threejs and aframe and surely I don't understand rotation, positions,world coordinates good enough but I think I did a decent work. Here the link:

```
https://glitch.com/~aframe-lookat-camera-working
```

I hope will be useful for somebody on the future.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579425/5250847), you have to remove or disable `look-controls` if you're overriding camera rotation manually. So you can do:

```js
var cameraEl = document.getElementById('camera');
cameraEl.setAttribute('look-controls', {enabled: false});
```

to disable the controls, perform your `lookAt()` operations, and then enable the controls via:

```js
cameraEl.setAttribute('look-controls', {enabled: true})
```

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87. I was doing this:  cameraEl.setAttribute('look-controls', enabled: false);    that was my error.   Thanks